# Tablas de verdad (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Es gusto esta por primera vez aquí, estoy aprendiendo a usar el lenguaje de programacion Kotlin, tengo que desarrollar una formula booleana con true o false, yo ya lo realice en Java y quedó asi

```
    private static final boolean VALUES[] = new boolean[]{true,false};
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("a\t\tb\t\tc\t\td\t\t(avb)\t(c^d)\t(avb) ->  (c^d)\t 'xor'(avb) -> !(cvd) \t !(avb) != (a=b) -> !(cvd)\r\n" + 
            "");
    for( boolean a : VALUES )               
    {
        for( boolean b: VALUES )
        {
            for( boolean c: VALUES )
            {
                for( boolean d: VALUES )
                {
                    for( boolean e: VALUES )
                    {
                        for( boolean f: VALUES )
                        {
                            System.out.println(a+"\t"+"\t"+b+"\t"+"\t"+c+"\t"+"\t"+d+"\t"+"\t"+or(a,b)+"\t"+and(c,d)+"\t\t"
                                    +conditional(or(a,b),and(c,d))+"\t"+"\t"+xor(e,f)+"\t"+"\t"+disequal(or(a,b),xor(e,f)));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static boolean or( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x || y;
}
public static boolean and( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x && y;
}
public static boolean xor( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x ^ y;
}
public static boolean conditional( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return !(x && y);

}
public static boolean bicontional( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x == y;
}   

public static boolean disequal ( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x != y;
}
```

Ahora quiero implementar una formula parecida en Android Studio con Kotlin y ha quedado asi

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val textview:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView



    val a = true;
    val b = false;



    val a1 = a && a
    val a2 = a && b
    val a3 = b && a
    val a4 = b && b


    val b1 = a || a
    val b2 = a || b
    val b3 = b || a
    val b4 = b || b


    val c1 = a xor a
    val c2 = a xor b
    val c3 = b xor a
    val c4 = b xor b

    val d1 = !a and b
    val d2 = a and !b


    val myString0 = "Tabla de AND \n";
        val myString2 = "$a  y $a = $a1 \n";
        val myString3 =  "$a  y $b = $a2 \n";
        val myString4 =  "$b  y $a = $a3 \n";
        val myString5=  "$b  y $b = $a4 \n";


    val myString6 = "\n";
    val myString7 = "Tabla de OR \n";

    val myString8 = "$a  y $a = $b1 \n";
    val myString9 =  "$a  y $b = $b2 \n";
    val myString10 =  "$b  y $a = $b3 \n";
    val myString11 =  "$b  y $b = $b4 \n";

    val myString12 = "\n";
    val myString13 = "Tabla de XOR \n";

    val myString14 = "$a  y $a = $c1 \n";
    val myString15 =  "$a  y $b = $c2 \n";
    val myString16 =  "$b  y $a = $c3 \n";
    val myString17 =  "$b  y $b = $c4 \n";



    val myString18 = "\n";
    val myString19 = "Tabla de NOT \n";

    val myString20 =  "$a  y $b = $d1 \n";
    val myString21 =  "$a  y $b = $d2 \n";




    textview.setText( myString0 + myString2 + myString3 + myString4 + myString5 +  myString6 + myString7 + myString8 + myString9 + myString10 + myString11 +myString12 +myString13 + myString14 + myString15
     + myString16 + myString17 + myString18 + myString19 + myString20 + myString21)

    textview.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod())
}
```

El codigo de Kotlin muestra las tablas de verdad quiero crear mi propia formula boolean parecido al primero, que debo cambiar en mi codigo de Kotlin ya investigado y no encuentro

Sera agradecido todo tipo de ayuda por parte de ustedes

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La traducción directa de tu código Java a Kotlin es:

```
private val VALUES = booleanArrayOf(true, false)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("a\t\tb\t\tc\t\td\t\t(avb)\t(c^d)\t(avb) ->  (c^d)\t 'xor'(avb) -> !(cvd) \t !(avb) != (a=b) -> !(cvd)\r\n" + "")
    for (a in VALUES) {
        for (b in VALUES) {
            for (c in VALUES) {
                for (d in VALUES) {
                    for (e in VALUES) {
                        for (f in VALUES) {
                            println(a.toString() + "\t\t" + b + "\t\t" + c + "\t\t" + d + "\t\t" + or(a,b) + "\t" + and(c, d) + "\t\t" + conditional(or(a, b), and(c, d)) + "\t\t" + xor(e,f) + "\t\t" + disequal(or(a, b), xor(e, f)))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun or(x: Boolean, y: Boolean): Boolean {
    return x || y
}

fun and(x: Boolean, y: Boolean): Boolean {
    return x && y
}

fun xor(x: Boolean, y: Boolean): Boolean {
    return x xor y
}

fun conditional(x: Boolean, y: Boolean): Boolean {
    return !(x && y)

}

fun bicontional(x: Boolean, y: Boolean): Boolean {
    return x == y
}

fun disequal(x: Boolean, y: Boolean): Boolean {
    return x != y
}
```

Este código lo ha hecho Android Studio solo con su conversor de clases Java a Kotlin, para usarlo solo tienes que clickar con el botón derecho en la clase (desde el explorador de project) y luego en la opción de convertir a clase kotlin, o directamente usar el atajo de teclado "Ctrl + Alt + Mayus + K".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo he probado en el compilador de Kotlin y me ha funcionado perfectamente gracias, ahora mi tarea en imprimir ese mismo resultado en Android.

Comment: Ok, pues lo mejor es que la marques como respuesta valida para que otros puedan encontrarlo mejor.